# Is calling my representatives about an issue repeatedly an effective way to get their attention?

Tags: united-states, legislative-process, lobbying

There are some issues I feel strongly about, so I have been calling my various representatives to share my thoughts with them. On some of these issues, I know that my representatives and I already disagree on the issues, so I would like to make my voice more forceful.

If I call my representatives about an issue multiple times, will they be more likely to consider what I have to say, or I become a nuisance? I've been calling my representatives in Congress and the Senate as well as my state's governor, and I might start calling my state's legislature as well.

I'm in the United States, so I'm mostly interested in answers specific to my country.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally calls/letters in favor/against an issue are tallied by staff and high level numbers are given to the representative. Calling or writing daily is likely to get noticed by the staff and potentially ignored on subsequent calls on the same issue. If you want to have more impact you need to find a way to get more people involved, encourage others to call or write, start an advocacy group or send a message as an existing group, create a petition, etc. Being a donor previously would also allow you to have more influence obviously.